# Original xbox 360 red light blinking please help

Tags: xbox-360

[image]
Please help. Im watching videos and they have 3 blinking lights, i have 4. Its an original xbox 360.

Comment: the redlights normally mean a hardware failure. I highly recommend contacting Microsoft directly. Support for 360 may be ended, as in Red Rings were definitely fixed for free during the 360's lifetime, but it's a better shot than asking here.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with the AV cable. Basically, the Xbox does not detect an AV input.

You can potentially fix the issue, with one of [these solutions](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/83094/XBOX+360+4+Red+Lights)

- Disconnect, then reconnect the AV/HDMI cable.
- Wipe down the contact area for the input, and if that still does not work, try a different cable.
- Flush the cache

There is a high potential that this is caused by overheating, which needs to be dealt with, advisedly by a professional, but it can be done yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The four lights mean that it's not detecting the TV.